# How to print YII Logger without Yii::app()->end

Tags: yii

I am using YII 1.0 logger but i am not able to print YII logs without Yii::app()->end.

Below is my test program :

```
$test = 123;
if($test){
    Yii::log('Test', CLogger::LEVEL_INFO, "This is for testing");
}
```

Below is my configuration settings :

```
'log' => array(
                'class' => 'CLogRouter',
                'routes' => array(
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',   
                        'levels' => 'trace, info, error, warning, vardump',                      
                    ),
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
                        'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
                        'levels' => 'error, warning, trace, notice',
                        'categories' => 'application',
                        'showInFireBug' => true,
                    ),
                     array(
                        'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                        'logFile'=>'custom.log',
                        'categories'=>'custom.*',
                    ),
                ),            
            ),
```

Is there something wrong in my code ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may learn [CLogger](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogger) api for more useful information.

```
Yii::getLogger()->flush(true);
```

Also hope it helps:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8671-force-message-routing-before-the-end-of-the-application/

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/8158-logger-and-flush-problem/

Answer (score 1):

Messages can be logged using `yii::log`,

**syntax:**

```
Yii::log($message, $level, $category);
```

**example:**

```
Yii::log("This is for testing","error","custom");
```